# Editar una tabla de mySQL usando PDO en PHP de manera sencilla

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo dos formularios, uno para borrar un tabla en la base de datos y otro para editarla. La de borrar tabla me funciona bien y la tengo así:

index:

```js
 <?php foreach($sites as $site): ?>
                
              <div class="col s6 md3">
                    <div class="card z-depth-0">
                        <div class="card-content center">
                            <h6><?php echo htmlspecialchars($site['name']); ?></h6>
                            
                            <a href="<?php $site['url'] ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($site['url']); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="forms-container">
                        <form action="delete.php" class="delete-form" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="<?php echo $site['id'] ?>" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
                            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
                        </form>
                        <!--<form action="" class="update-form" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="<?php echo $site['id'] ?>" class="btn brand z-depth-0">-->
                                <li><a href="update.php" class="btn brand z-depth-2">Edit</a></li>
                                <!--<button type="submit" name="update" value="Edit" class="btn brand z-depth-0"><a href="update.php" class="material-icons right">edit</a>Edit</button>-->
                            <!--</form>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>  

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

delete.php:

```js
<?php 
include('config/db_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $id = $_POST['site_id'];
    $pdoDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM sites WHERE id=:id ";
    $pdoDeleteQuery_run = $connect->prepare($pdoDeleteQuery);
    $pdoDeleteQuery_exec = $pdoDeleteQuery_run->execute(array(":id"=>$id));

    if($pdoDeleteQuery_exec){
        echo '<script>alert("Funcionó!")</script>';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("No se pudo realizar la acción, intentelo de nuevo en unos minutos")</script>';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}

?>
```

Entonces quise imitarla para intentar hacer un formulario para editar la tabla. El problema es que no entiendo muy php y parece que el update.php me corre dos veces y no aparece el html de `update.php` (aunque antes si me aparecía pero por entonces no me cogía los datos del formulario del index)

index:

```
<form action="update.php" class="update-form" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="<?php echo $site['id'] ?>" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
                            <button data-target="editmodal" type="submit" name="update" value="Edit" class="btn brand z-depth-0"><i class="material-icons right">edit</i>Edit</button>
                        </form>
```

```js
<?php 

include('config/db_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
 
    $site_name = $_POST['site_name'];
    $site_url = $_POST['site_url'];
    $id = $_POST['site_id'];
    $pdoEditQuery = "UPDATE `sites` SET name='$site_name',url='$site_url' WHERE id='$id' ";
    $pdoEditQuery_run = $connect->prepare($pdoDeleteQuery);
    $pdoEditQuery_exec = $pdoDeleteQuery_run->execute(array(":id"=>$id));

    if($pdoEditQuery_exec){
        echo '<script>alert("Funcionó!")</script>';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("No se pudo realizar la acción, intentelo de nuevo en unos minutos")</script>';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <?php include('templates/header.php'); ?>

    <section class="container white-text">
        <h4 class="center">Edit a Site</h4>
        <form action="update.php" method="POST" class="white add-form">
            <label for="">New Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="site_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($site_name) ?>">
            
            <label for="">New Link:</label>
            <input type="text" name="site_url" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($site_url) ?>" >
           
            <div class="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

    <?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?>

</html>
```

Intento hacer lo mismo que con delete.php pero la diferencia es que necesito llevarme los datos del formulario en index hacia update.php y no ejecutar el script de php directamente y no tengo ni idea como entender básicamente que esta ocurriendo aquí.

Curiosamente el SQL si funciona porque cuando le doy a EDIT me elimina los datos y me lo susitutuye por un espacio en blanco, pero ni siquiera da la opción a aparecer antes el formulario que se encuentra en el html de `update.php`

Comment: en el formulario abajo asignas nombre submit al button y en la verificación validas si 'update' fue asignado que corresponde al nombre que decías querer asignar en el pequeño snipet situado más arriba. **¡Cambia el nombre!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dice @quevedo en su comentario, tienes que cambiar el `name` del `input` que envía el formulario.

Cambiar esto:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
```

Por esto:

```
<input type="submit" name="update" value="save" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
```

Porque haces una verificación en base a la clave `update` :

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    //...
}
```

Hay más errores en la parte de la consulta:

1. tu consulta para el `UPDATE` no es una consulta preparada
2. muchas de las variables conservan nombres calcados del código del `DELETE`. Recomendaría que para casos como estos uses nombres genéricos, por ejemplo: `$sql` para la consulta, `$stmt` para la preparación. Son variables que se usarán solamente en ese ámbito, por tanto difícilmente podrán confundirse con otras
3. Así como en (1) vimos que se necesita escribir una consulta preparada, ésta va a tener tres datos que luego debes crear y pasar en el `execute()`. Aquí lo haremos en forma de array

Apliquemos esos tres parches:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $site_name = $_POST['site_name'];
    $site_url = $_POST['site_url'];
    $id = $_POST['site_id'];
    $pdoEditQuery = "UPDATE `sites` SET name=:name, url=:url WHERE id=:id";
    #Metemos los datos en un array
    $params=array(":name"=>$site_name ,":url"=>$site_url , ":id"=>$id);
    $pdoEditQuery_run = $connect->prepare($pdoEditQuery);
    #Pasamos $params en el execute
    $pdoEditQuery_exec = $pdoEditQuery_run->execute($params);

    //... resto del código
```

---

> ## Nota final
>
> Para verificar que un `UPDATE`, `DELETE` o `INSERT` ocurrió **realmente**, lo correcto en PDO
>   es usar **[`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php)**.

Comment: Gracias una ultima pregunta, me acabo de dar cuenta que mi enfoque no va a funcionar porque cuando le doy a EDIT o bien le pongo un botón que me lleva a la página update.php (pero no me recoge el id que tiene que borrar), o bien le pongo el formulario pero entonces me corre el codigo del update.php y entonces al usuario ni siquiera se le muestra el html de update.php. Hay alguna forma de enviar el id desde un botón a update.php? (Estoy renderizando cada id con un <?php foreach en index.php, pero no tengo manera de llevarme esa "informacion" del id a update.php para que se edite el correcto id)

Comment: @JavierCake haces unos minutos edité la pregunta porque había un error en la variable `$pdoEditQuery`, yo había puesto esto mal: `WHERE id=:id` porque lo tenía con los dos puntos al final, creo que es por eso que no tu funciona, compáralo con el código como está ahora.